# Navigating AppDelegate class to Another ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, navigation, appdelegate

I am using login with google option in the app. When User logged in using Google successfully then I want to navigate/show the another scree.

I tried so many codes to navigate AppDelegate class to another class, but its not working.

[Here the project](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Gkd8RilBsFvBuNvJ97ZAEsU9CAq62mur/view?usp=sharing)

Following code I tried to navigate,

```
let mainStoryboardIpad : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let initialViewControlleripad : UIViewController = mainStoryboardIpad.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeScreenVC") as UIViewController
    self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    self.window?.rootViewController = initialViewControlleripad
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

And below code

```
 let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
   let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier :"HomeScreenVC") as! HomeScreenVC
   let navController = UINavigationController.init(rootViewController: viewController)

      if let window = self.window, let rootViewController = window.rootViewController {
          var currentController = rootViewController
          while let presentedController = currentController.presentedViewController {
              currentController = presentedController
           }
              currentController.present(navController, animated: true, completion: nil)
      }
```

and below code also

```
let mainStoryboard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let initialViewControlleripad : UIViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeScreenVC") as! HomeScreenVC


        if let navigationController = self.window?.rootViewController as? UINavigationController
        {
            navigationController.pushViewController(initialViewControlleripad, animated: true)
        }
        else
        {
            print("Navigation Controller not Found")
        }
```

I wrote this code inside AppDelegate class in below method, when user logged in using google successfully

```
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any]) -> Bool {
  return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(url)

}
```

I tried those codes, but its not working.

Can anyone help to solve this, I already gave link of project You can download the see the code.

Comment: Hii have you check in iOS12 ? it's working or not

Comment: How are you calling those methods. So the user tap in singing with google button and you want to navigate to another screen or you want to run some VC if some condition occurs and se the VC

Comment: When I click to google sign button, when will enter the login credentials and then after logging successfully in app delegate class we will get response i.e user data. When we get/receive the data of user i.e user is logged in successfully after it has to navigate to next VC i.e HomeScreenVC